# SSH ubuntu desktop 16.04 installation on a remote live CD

Tags: command-line, 16.04, system-installation, ssh, live-cd

There's a remote PC where I want to install ubuntu 16.04. The user at the other end has a live CD booted up and has got openssh-server set-up. Is there a way to run the installation process through SSH using CLI?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably easier to use X Forwarding and run `ubiquity`, the graphical installer.

Comment: thanks muru, was just writing the anwser when yours came in. will set yours as answer.

Comment: Mine's just a comment, yours is the answer. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @muru do you know if there's a ncurses style installer on the desktop live cd (similar to the network/ubuntu server installer)?

Comment: I don't know if that can be started by a command, but see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetworkConsole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier than expected. On the live CD:

```
dpkg -l | grep install
```

Found out that the GUI ubuntu installer was called **ubiquity**. First I connected to the remote PC via SSH using X Forwarding:

```
ssh user@host -X
```

Then I simply ran:

```
sudo ubiquity
```

[image]